How to create a square coordinate frame with x in 0~0.72 and y in 0~50 for plotting points in it?
Like the question title, I'm trying to achieve this, like the following MWE:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[unit vector ratio={\fpeval{625/9} 1},xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=0.72,ymax=50,xtick={0,0.24,...,0.72},ytick={0,10,...,50}]

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I should set the unit vector ratio={\fpeval{625/9} 1} to keep the coornidate frame square, however it returns me Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgfmath@x. Unless I set the unit vector ratio like unit vector ratio={\fpeval{625/27} 1} that much smaller than 625/9. How can I solve the problem?

Whats' more, I have set it like unit vector ratio={\fpeval{625/27} 1} and then add [xscale=3] after \begintikzpicture, however the labels in it were also scaled...


Why don't you set width and height while discarding ratio?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=6cm, height=6cm, scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=0.72,
ymin=0, ymax=50,
xtick distance=0.24, ytick distance=10,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


